# Excel 2010 Multiple Cell Worksheet Change Trigger

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where I have multiple options to choose from based on a data validation combo box. Depending on what value from that combo box I select, I then populate various other cells in the same row. So I have something like the following.

```
Combo Box | VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell
Combo Box | VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell
Combo Box | VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell | Another VBA Populated Cell
```

If I delete the value from the data validation combo box it reverts all changed cells back to their "default" state. What I want to be able to do is select multiple rows of data validation combo boxes, hit the delete key and have Excel loop over each item in the selection. The problem I'm running into is that the worksheet_change() function doesn't seem to trigger/fire when I do this.

Within and outside of a range intersect I've tried trapping the delete key, testing if application.selection was greater than 1 and I cannot manage to get the Worksheet_Change() function to fire when I select multiple rows of cells and hit the delete key.

Is this a limitation of Excel or is there something I have not considered/been able to find via Googling?

**Edit:** To see if I can make things a bit more clear: The combo boxes are from the data validation tool (Data --> Data Validation). They are not the ActiveX controls that can be embedded into worksheets. The file I'm working on... Think of it like an invoice form. The first column, with the combo boxes, lets me select from a couple of transaction types. So let's say debit or credit to continue with the invoice form idea. If a line is a debit, I want to populate other cells in that row with certain values and if it's a credit I want to populate those cells with different values.

What I'm trying to do now is be able to select a range of cells. So let's say I have a form with 10 rows of debit/credit entries. Then I realize that rows 5-10 are from another invoice so I want to select cells A5-A10, hit the delete key and have that trigger some VBA code that will loop over rows 5-10 and set cells in columns B, C and D to a default value I program in. So I want to be able to trigger Worksheet_Change when I'm operating on a range of cells instead of just an individual cell.

Comment: Do you actually have ComboBoxes inserted into the worksheet? What Excel version do you run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should activate if you change or delete any cells in the Range("A1:A4"). It will tell you how many of the cells in the range have been updated. This is assuming you are using an in cell drop-down based on a list for the "data validation combo boxes" you are talking about.  (Meaning you used the Data->Data Validation root.)  Your terminology seems to be a little unclear, so hopefully that is what you mean.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
        Counter = 0
        For Each myCell In Target
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Next
        MsgBox (Counter & " cells have been updated.")
    End If
End Sub
```

[MSDN Worksheet Change Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
[Application.Intersect Method Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: That works fine for one cell at a time, but what I'm looking to do is have say cell A1 _through_ A4 selected and trigger the Worksheet_Change function when I do it so I can loop over every cell selected and perform some operation.

Comment: It should work when you select multiple cells as well.  Select A1 & A2 for instance, and the event will still fire.

Comment: Thanks to KingOfTheNerds for taking the time to edit the code to make it clearer that it does indeed affect multiple cell selections.